# How to avoid increasing the height of an adjacent textbox when expanding an expander

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Width="250" Text="bla bla"/>
    <Expander Header="Address" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Width="250"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Width="250"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Width="250"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

This is a Grid with one row and two columns.The left column contains a TextBox and in the right column an Expander is placed.

When I open the Expander, the height of the TextBox will be increased, so that it matches the height of the Expander. But I want the TextBox to keep its height, when the Expander is opened.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `TextBox` is in the Row you set the height to auto, it will grow with the Grid's Row.

The easiest way to fix your layouting issue will be doing something like this:

```
<TextBox Width="250" Text="bla bla" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Setting an explicit height and orientation will prevent the `TextBox` from growing and moving.

An alternative way might be introducing some more Rows and set the Expanders `Rowspan` accordingly, but that might be overkill for your situation